# Black screen after changing primary monitor

Tags: linux-mint, multi-monitor

I've just completed a clean install of Linux Mint Maya x64. I am using two monitors (default screen of my laptop and external HP w2007v). The problem is that after I've changed my primary monitor to the external one (did it using control center), I get black screen on both after login and I can't do anything.

Is there any way to make my computer work again? It doesn't matter now which one will be default, I just want it to work again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new user from the command line.

- At the login screen hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to get a text console
- Log in with you regular user credentials, you'll be prompted with a `$`-prompt
- Check the command syntax by entering `sudo useradd`
- Create the the new user by entering `sudo useradd ...`
- hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to return to the GUI login, if this doesn't work try the same with F8 ...
- Login with your temporary user.

An alternative is to clean out your home directory instead of creating the new user (but it is partially the same trick), but that is probably not what you want. You'll loose all your own files and settings. The important files are usually hidden, you'll need to use `ls -al` to see them. It depends on your display manager which exact directory contains the bad settings.

Comment: An where does mint store the settings? Is there no way to revert the changes?